# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync times out on production server

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to Authenticate our Google Apps users against our directory to restrict access to some of our in house applications.
It runs perfectly on my desktop but does not run on our production server. It hangs on `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()`

It creates the Google.DP.Auth folder in the GoogleStorage as it is supposed to, but it never creates the `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user` file. I never even get the Consent Screen. However if I copy the `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user' from my desktop to the server it works fine on all subsequent requests.

In my desperation i have overridden implemented my own `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker`, `AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp` and `LocalServerCodeReceiver` classes and have found that the line that it never gets further than is `var context = await listner.GetContextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`in the `LocalServerCodeReceiver` class. (This was only done so I could throw some debug info into a log on the server to figure out what was going)
Here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            googleGo();
        }
    }
protected async void googleGo()
    {
     var f = new Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/GoogleStore/DP.Google.Auth"));
        UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets { 
                ClientId = "XX", 
                ClientSecret = "YY" },
            new[] { 
                DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupMember, 
                DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupReadonly, 
                Oauth2Service.Scope.UserinfoEmail,
                Oauth2Service.Scope.UserinfoProfile },
            "user",
            System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
            f);
        Oauth2Service service = new Oauth2Service(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Test"

            });
        var userinfo = service.Userinfo.Get();
        var s = userinfo.Execute();
 }
```

Hopefully i am missing something easy that someone can point out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know anything about Googles API, however you could download the source code and debug it. (Step into GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()) and see exactly whats going on line by line during runtime.

Comment: Hi @BjarkeCK. I have done that. I have overridden the three classes involved and stepped thru them on my machine, and added logging to them for the production version as I cant debug on that. As mentioned in the last paragraph it hangs on `var context = await listner.GetContextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` with listner being httpListener event.

Comment: What is redirect URI set to on developer console?

Comment: 1. Does it happen only in your production servers? 2. Does the network settings (firewall, or other stuff) are configured the same for this server and your local machine? 3. Can you try to use https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/PromptCodeReceiver.cs on your server, just to make sure that this instance doesn't stuck? Let's take it from there.. Sorry!

Comment: @Peleyal I think you might be on to it with the firewall. We have some port restrictions in place on our cloud server. 
I think the listener in `LocalServerCodeReceiver.cs` (which generates a random port to listen on) is what is causing the grief. Is there a reason why this is randomized? Am i missing something? Why would I want to open a bunch of ports on my server to utilize the dotnet client?

Comment: As an update with all TCP ports open (verified by NMAP) i still run into the same issue.

Comment: Further updates, spun up a VM template with server 2008r2 internally and got the exact same issue. It seems that the `Process.Start(authorizationUrl)` that spins up a browser with the consent screen on my desktop, never starts on the server. Using Fiddlr on the servers i see absolutely no interaction with Google

Comment: @DaImTo I have http://localhost/authorize and http://servername/authorize

Comment: Turns out that the .Net API that I was using is not for Web applications. I will add an answer that shows how i handled this for web eventually